# Java lock and unlock in different methods. How to try/finally?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to use the try/finally with locks.

When I have `lock()` and `unlock()` in the same place, I just use the `try/finally` block as the JavaDoc also suggests:

```
lock.lock();
try{
  // do something
} finally {
  lock.unlock();
}
```

I am wondering what's the best practice to use the `try/finally` when the `lock()` and `unlock()` calls are in separate methods.

For example, consider the following:

```
public class X {
  private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

  public void pickUp(){
    lock.lock();
    // do something
  }

  public void putDown(){
    // do something
    lock.unlock();
  }
}
```

What I would do is to put the `try/finally` block on the upper level, that is, whenever I call the methods `pickUp()` and `putDown()`. For example, inside of the `run()` method:

```
// class code
X x = new X();

public void run(){
  try{
    x.pickUp();
    // do something
  } finally {
    x.putDown();
  }
}
```

Is this the proper way?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The danger of that is if your `//do something` in `putDown()` could throw an exception that might prevent `lock.unlock()` from being called; so you would need to write `putDown()` in such a way that `lock.unlock()` would definitely be called (e.g. another `try/finally` block).

Comment: Well, but if the `//do something` could throw an exception, I could add a `catch` clause to the same `try/finally` block, couldn't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a very good candidate to apply the [***execute around method pattern***](http://www.karthikscorner.com/sharepoint/design-patterns-execute-around-method-pattern/).

If a client of your class needs to do something with a resource that needs proper initialization and/or proper cleanup, you can leave the cleanup in the hands of the client, and hope that documentation and fail fast behavior nudges the client into properly handling the resource.

The execute around method pattern delas with this conundrum by taking the initialization and cleaup out of the client's hands again. Basically you introduce a method that does the initialization and cleanup of the resource properly, and in between hands it off to a `Consumer` of that resource.

Ideally you can even completely encapsulate the methods that do the initialization and cleanup.

As an example, based on your example code :

```
private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

private void pickUp() { // now private
  lock.lock();
  // do something
}

private void putDown() { // now private
  // do something
  lock.unlock();
}

public void use(Consumer<X> consumer) {
  try {
    pickUp();
    consumer.accept(this);  // client gets its hands on the properly initialized resource.
  } finally {
    putDown();
  }
}
```

The client can still do messy things with the resource, such as using it outside of the consumer, after cleanup, but this is already harder to do. And the hard part, remembering to proper init and cleanup, is no longer the client's concern.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'll have more time tonight to expand it

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik hope you like it better now :)